# Blog on my Google Apps Domain

Tags: domains, blog, google-workspace

I just got a domain with Google Apps.

What are the options for hosting a blog on my domain ?

I know of the option of using Blogger hosted on my domain but was wondering if there are any other options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a blog using blogger and then [insert it into a google site with an `iframe`](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dPh0ATV5ic) or use the 'announcement' type page in sites which can be [configured into a blog](http://edutraining.googleapps.com/Training-Home/module-5-sites/chapter-3/6-1).

Comment: Ha... fancy seeing you here.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create your blog on blogger.com, and then go into the administration section and add your domain so you can have something like blog.yourdomain.com.

Blogger has a lot of really great professional looking themes, and I would be afraid of losing some of that appeal by embedding that in a Google Site.

I think that embedding your blog in Google Sites might look a little choppy, but it really depends on your level of expertise with Sites and what you're looking for.

Here is a Google Support URL to get you started:  http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/static.py?hl=en&ts=1233381&page=ts.cs